# Sharepoint _x0020_ What to convert to?

Tags: c#, csom, sharepoint-2016

I´m using CSOM to get Data from a onpremis sharepoint 2016.
Everything works fine until I want to access a DocumentLibray containing a space.
The spaceis represented as `_x0020_`. When fetching all DocumentLibraries from the sharepoint i get `Project_x0020_Files`, however when I want to access a DocumentLibrary containing this, it does not exist.

I've noticed that in the browser the `_x0020_` is replaced with `%20` however when i do this in my code, it is not working.

In both cases i get this exception:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'List 'Master_x0020_Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'URL...'.'
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> Project.Helper.SharePointConnector.FoldersAndFiles.AnonymousMethod__0() in SharePointConnector.cs
> [External Code]

What do I have to convert the `_x0020_` to in order for it to work?